# Best practice to convert screen design to XML in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'll start with the fact that I'm quite new to Android 
app development and I came across a real App screen, that I thought will be a good practice to convert to XML.

Although I successfully copied some parts of it, I believe I lack a little bit of knowledge to achieve that goal. So I hope to learn from your answers.
Please keep the answer as clean as possible since I wish to learn forward from it.

Thanks in advance! [image: App's screen]

## NOTE:

1) The icons on the gray line are clickable.

2) the X on the light blue line is clickable and deletes the line.

Comment: Do you want to do that screen from screenshot into XML layout and you want to know some best practices for that?

Comment: I want to know how would you code the XML. since I failed to do so, and I wish to learn from your answer. If you wish to just theoretically tell me how or point some important stuff that's ok. And if you will code the actual XML that's even better. @YaroslavOvdiienko

Comment: I will provide today at the evening(+2 by UTC) for you sample with XML how I would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I create for you quick **demo** app(*it is not as good as for commerce practice*). How it looks and works from inside you may see here in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/yaroslav-android/itay-braha-help). Hope I help you!

**Things you try to avoid**:

1. hardcoded text & colors in XML
2. not consistent id-naming
3. none-dimensional code *****, for example like this -  `android:textSize="16sp"`

***** - I mean use `dimens.xml`, for instance - `android:textSize="@dimen/default_input_text_size"`

I will recommend you read a great book:

> Clean Code - Robert Martin

Also, I support @FrancislainyCampos post. You should try to read also about [design](https://material.io/design/) and [develop tools](https://material.io/develop/android/) to think and do more consistently with Google recommendations.

[image: from your screenshot above]

Comment: Greart work and references too! Simple, clean, exactly what I was looking for. In one word - perfect!

Comment: @ItayBraha happy to read it! I wish you good luck with future tasks and coding!

Answer (score 1):

Although I've heard of some new tools that proclaim to be able to automate the task of converting design screens to xml, I don't think that's wide spread around the Android community yet. I think the best tip for you here is just to actually type each element on the screen not converting it but *making* the layout happen. There's a few tutorials on how to use Constrainst Layout to achieve that on Youtube. I'd also suggest this [course](https://eu.udacity.com/course/android-basics-user-interface--ud834) here on Udacity that explains the step by step on creating your first screens for Android.

Hope that helps.